# Sending data between Flask and JS using AJAX for chrome extension

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, flask, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to use AJAX calls to send data back and forth between my Javascript frontend for my chrome extension and the Flask API where I plan to use my Machine Learning code.

**content.js**

```
console.log("Application GO");

function colorChanger() {
  let tweets = document.querySelectorAll("article");
  tweets.forEach(function (tweet) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
          url: "/_api_call",
          traditional: "true",
          data: JSON.stringify({tweet}),
          dataType: "json"
          });
  });

    tweet.setAttribute("style", "background-color: red;");
  });
}

let timer = setInterval(colorChanger, 2000);
```

**flask code**

```
from flask import Flask, flash, request, redirect, url_for
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

@app.route('/_api_call', methods=['GET'])
def fake_news_detector():
    data = request.get_json()
    with open('temp.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(data)
    return data
```

**Error**

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
content.js:11 (anonymous function) // which points to line -  $(document).ready(function () {
```

I'm new to both Javascript and Flask. Any help would be really helpful. Thanks a lot !

Comment: What specifically is the issue (what is the current behavior vs expected)? Do you get errors? Have you used the browser developer tools and/or a traffic debugging tools such as Fiddler to watch the call and observe what you are sending and where? Have you read up on asynchronous calls in javascript?

Comment: if you get error message when you run it then show it in question (not in comment) as text (not image). Don't expect that we will run code to see problems. You have to all describe in question.

Comment: in `$.ajax()` you only send data to Flask but you don't execute function which will get result from Flask. You need `$.ajax(..., success: function)`

Comment: Extremely sorry. I have included the error script. Do have a look at it now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is `JSON.stringify({temp})`? You never define a variable of the name `temp` anywhere.

Comment: I've edited it.

Comment: @TonyStark Did you include jQuery before this script is run? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined

Comment: No @scrappedcola, I didn't include it. What code shall I add there ?

Comment: I see you've written `{tweet}` now. `tweet` is a DOM element list. What exactly do you expect does `{tweet}` do? Have you this checked that this actually produces the object you want to send? Because I would be *very* surprised if it did.

Comment: I'm currently just trying to send the tweet as a whole. I'd be modifying it later. The tweet just holds the DOM of the selected tweet in twitter. For now I'd like to complete a connection between the frontend and the Flask API, and then I can send whatever data I want and also include my ML code in Flask.

Comment: @TonyStark `$.ajax` is part of the jQuery framework and not vanilla JS. To use you need to include it in your code, like any other 3rd party library. Start out with https://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/.

Comment: HI, add jquery cdn i.e : `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Thanks @Swati, but isn't that used for including jquery in html. I don't think I can use it in a javascript code.

Comment: You need to include this else jquery code will throw above error . Put that line at top inside `content.js` file

Answer (score 1):

`$(document).ready` and `$.ajax` requires `jQuery`

`fetch` and `window.addEventListener` works in almost all latest browsers

`$(document).ready` => `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(evt) {})`

`$.ajax` => `fetch`

**Note:** Calling `$(document).ready` again and again inside loop for each tweet is not a good option it will run a bunch of code again and again instead `setInterval` can be called once after `document` loading completes.

content.js

```js
async function Request(url = '', data = {}, method = 'POST') {
  // Default options are marked with *
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: method, // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
    mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
    cache: 'no-cache', // *default, no-cache, reload, force-cache, only-if-cached
    credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': "application/json;charset=utf-8",
      // 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
    redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error
    referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', // no-referrer, *no-referrer-when-downgrade, origin, origin-when-cross-origin, same-origin, strict-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin, unsafe-url
    body: JSON.stringify(data) // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
  });
  return response.json(); // parses JSON response into native JavaScript objects
}

console.log("Application GO");

function colorChanger() {
  let tweets = document.querySelectorAll("article");

  tweets.forEach(function (tweet) {
    let response = Request("/_api_call", {tweet});
    tweet.setAttribute("style", "background-color: red;");
  });
}

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    console.log('Called once after document load');
    let timer = setInterval(colorChanger, 2000);
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Should I make modifications in the flask code too ?

Comment: @TonyStark There are 2 changes: you can change `return data` to `return jsonify(data)` if you are want to return json from backend and you are handling only `GET` method in `_api_call` route which should be either both `GET` & `POST` or just `POST`

Comment: Thanks again. But the chrome extension still doesn't work. Can you have a look at the entire code [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14_guO5PoV-IB0vV1CycXl2cFxRIL_xHJ/view?usp=sharing) if your free.

Comment: @TonyStark check [this](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/9a915e9f0a338f56a3583d6b712fc4ac20201220150810/da00fb) i have include readme for information.

Comment: @TonyStark sorry i did'nt read chrome extension word in you question.

Comment: It's fine. I should have included it in the heading. Anyway I could use this code for a chrome extension ?

Comment: @TonyStark i forget to include one information you have to properly indent python code if you are using space then you have to stick with spaces and if you are using tabs then you have to use tabs for indentation in one line you used tabs and in all file you used space.

Comment: @TonyStark i created a temp html page for extension and use that to test it

Comment: Yes, I got it. I'll stick with tabs and I'll check the temp html page too. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: The code doesn't send information back and forth. I seem to get this [error](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KcIYb-LpMpnFUyGZh56FOPa1Q8mLsJWj/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @TonyStark did you started flask server

Comment: Yes, I did. It still gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't have jQuery installed so you can't access `$` and your error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

is saying that. you should include jQuery in your `js` code in order to use `$` and call ajax. just follow `@scrappedcola` comment and follow the instructions there to add jQuery script.

second you need to define the endpoint as `POST`.

```
@app.route('/_api_call', methods=['POST'])
```